# Django get Deadline Date excluding weekends

Tags: python, django, django-models

> How to get the exact Deadline date not the number of days in Django Models
>   exclude weekends? My code work good but I want to exclude weekends.

```
Deadline = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.today() + timedelta(days=15))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

Models.py

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    deadline = models.DateTimeField()
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.deadline is None:
            now = datetime.now()
            num_days = 0
            while num_days < 15:
                now = now + timedelta(days=1)
                if now.isoweekday() not in [6,7]:
                    num_days+=1
            self.deadline = now
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```